# -XX:MaxPermSize setting was not reflected

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, permgen, jdk1.7

I am using below JVM opts in my application on Linux server

```
-server -Xms3g -Xmx3g -Xmn512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xss256k -Xloggc:${gc_log_file} 
-verbose:gc -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseParallelGC 
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=300000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=300000 
-XX:+AggressiveOpts 
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintConcurrentLocks -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=20
```

But this setting was not effective on that node and MaxPermSize is taken as ***140m*** instead of ***256m***

Details:

```
MemTotal:        5925728 kB
java version     "1.7.0_251"
```

Heap

```
PSYoungGen      total 471040K, used 122995K [0x00000007e0000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
eden space 416256K, 25% used [0x00000007e0000000,0x00000007e6784d38,0x00000007f9680000)
from space 54784K, 31% used [0x00000007fca80000,0x00000007fdb18000,0x0000000800000000)
to   space 53248K, 0% used [0x00000007f9680000,0x00000007f9680000,0x00000007fca80000)
ParOldGen       total 2621440K, used 1146547K [0x0000000740000000, 0x00000007e0000000, 0x00000007e0000000)
object space 2621440K, 43% used [0x0000000740000000,0x0000000785face28,0x00000007e0000000)
PSPermGen       total 140800K, used 140471K [0x0000000730000000, 0x0000000738980000, 0x0000000740000000)
object space 140800K, 99% used [0x0000000730000000,0x000000073892de90,0x0000000738980000)
```

As per gclog statements, PermGen reached 99% when it reached 140m

***object space 140800K, 99% used***

*How to force java process to consider MaxPermSize VM opts for PermGen?*

Comment: Do you have `Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`? If no, that's why the generation doesn't get bigger. If you want to have an init size of 256m you can use `XX:PermSize` (but i'm not sure it's necessary in your case)

Comment: I don't have PermGen OOM since I am killing my application when it reaches 99%

Comment: Did you already try setting ```PermSize``` to the same amount of ```256m``` ?

Comment: No. I set only MaxPermSize

Comment: PermSize is like the initial setting and MaxPermSize is the max. If you absolutely want to reach 256m at JVM startup, you might want to set both to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PSPermGen       total 140800K, used 140471K
  object space 140800K, 99% used
```

`140800K` is the allocated permanent generation, not the maximum allocable.

> I don't have PermGen OOM since I am killing my application when it reaches 99%

If you don't kill it, you will see the permanent generation growing to accomodate new allocations.